# import fsspec throws error (AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get')

Tags: import, attributes, kedro, fsspec

import fsspec throws error (AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get')
[[image]]

Comment: Note that this is only an issue on python 3.7

Comment: Can you please share the source where it says other Python version would work?

Comment: It showed up in py37 tests. importlib-metadata is a backport package on py37, but builtin for >=38.

Answer (score 0):

@Abjiji Das

Please pin `importlib-metadata<5.0.0`, this is an issue from `fsspec` side and the older kedro does not have an upper bound for it.

See details here:
https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/1895

Comment: Used importlib-metadata==3.10.0 for Kedro 0.17.3 not helping. Same error